# Does any know how to extract a tensorflow DNNRegressor model and evaluate manually?

Tags: java, tensorflow, regression, real-time

I am trying to use a DNNRegressor model in a java realtime context, unfortunately this requires a garbage free implementation. It doesn't look like tensorflow-light offers a GC free implementation. The path of least resistance would be to extract the weights and re-implement the NN manually. Has anyone tried extracting the weights from a regression model and implementing the regression manually, and if so could you describe any pitfalls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if your conclusion

> The path of least resistance would be to extract the weights and re-implement the NN manually.

is actually true. It sounds to me like you want to use the trained model in an Android mobile application. I personally do not know much about that, but I am sure there are efficient ways to do exactly that.

However, assuming you actually need to extract the weights there are multiple ways to do this.

One straight forward way to do this is to implement the exact network you want yourself with Tensorflows low level API instead of using the canned `DNNRegressor` class (which is deprecated btw.). That might sound unnecessarily complex, but is actually quite easy and has the upside of you being in full control.

A general way to get all trainable variables is to use Tensorflows [trainable_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) method.

Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907703/extracting-neural-net-weights-using-tensorflows-tf-contrib-learn-dnnclassifier?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) might help you.

In terms of pitfalls I don't really believe there are any. At the end of the day you are just storing a bunch of floats. You should probably make sure to use an appropriate file format like hdf5 and sufficient float precision.

Comment: is tf.estimator.DNNRegressor deprecated? (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNRegressor)

Comment: No sorry that is the right one. I was not aware that they just moved it and kept the same name, I personally do not use the high level API at the moment. I meant [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor) one.

Comment: unfortunately, tensorflow light (the android mobile approach) still generates garbage and isn't suitable for realtime java. It turns out it was really straight forward to extract the weight and bias's using the links you provided and re-implement a garbage free version in Java. Thanks for the help!